# Global Script Filter, ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the following script filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "states": "co"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {

        "script" : {
            "script" : "count++; count <= 3",
            "params" : {
                "count" : 0
            }
        }
          }
        ]
      }

    }
  }
}
```

With this query, I'm expecting to get one results back. But since we have 5 shards set up on our ES server, I actually get back 15 results.

Is there a way with a script filter to make the count variable global, or so that the variable is not reset when searching another shard?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make global variables using script filters. But alternately, why don't you use the `size` parameter to limit the number of documents you want?

Comment: Specifying the size doesn't change anything. If I set the size to 1, it will still return 15 results because there are 5 shards. 3 results are less than three * 5 = 15.

Comment: I don't quite understand `I'm expecting to get one results back`. How do you expect to get one result back? From the description of what you wish to achieve, you will still get 3 results back at the least. Can you clarify a bit more?